# Fecha corta personalizada C#

Tags: c#, date, datetime, timestamp

Como puedo personalizar una fecha en una variable `String` (`TiempoFecha`) para obtener algo asi:

> El Viernes, 24 Feb a las 03:22 p. m.

Lo intente de la siguiente forma:

```
string FechaCorta = Convert.ToString(DateTime.ParseExact(TiempoFecha, "El dddd, dd, MM a las hh:mm tt", null));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que existen varias formas pero yo haria algo asi:

```
 DateTime TiempoFecha = DateTime.Now;
        string strFecha = String.Format("el dia {0}, de {1} a las {2}", 
TiempoFecha.DayOfWeek, TiempoFecha.Month, TiempoFecha.ToString("hh:mm tt"));
```

la muestra o ejemplo lo encuentras [acá](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kG79lx)

**Actualización** debes de tener en cuenta el culture en el ejemplo esta en ingles que es por defecto.

Para Culture info revisa este [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837000/convert-datetime-from-english-to-spanish/6837047)

Como te dije hay varias formas, y creo que esta es mejor!

```
Console.WriteLine("el dia  " + TiempoFecha.ToString("dd, MMMM, yyyy", culture) + ".");
```

ya miraras cual te gusta!

Comment: Ger, disculpa, me equivoque en el post. La var es string, lo que me genera que no reconozca lo que es DayOfWeek, Month, etc. Como lo harias siendo un string?

Comment: igual mira que strFecha que coloque es de tipo string pero en tu post tienes datetime.parse a tiempoFecha